# MvvmCross Close does not invoke DidMoveToParentController

Tags: ios, navigation, mvvmcross

I am trying to ensure all my views and view models are cleaned up ready for garbage collection. However we have a scenario where a view is effectively acting as a modal view, it is not truly modal, but we do not use the standard navigation back  to dismiss it. Instead we have a cancel button which is bound to a command in the viewmodel which calls Close(this).

The problem is that the call to close does not invoke DidMoveToParentViewController in the corresponding view. I need to be able to do this to ensure the view can be cleaned up e.g. remove any other event subscriptions etc.

Note - This is an iOS app. We are using a CustomViewPresenter which inherits from MvxModalNavSupportTouchViewPresenter

Is this a bug, or is there any way to make this happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found that my view was implementing the IMvxModelTouchView interface. Removing this fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my view was implementing the IMvxModelTouchView interface. Removing this fixed the issue.